# Various ways to combine two different result sets and do the iteration and sum

Tags: c#, list, linq, c#-4.0, generic-list

Here  I have  a class `List1` and classes `List2`,`ListViewModel` for combining two datasets, and I have two different result sets, each list having four values and I need to combine them as a single resultset with 4  rows and need to do the iteration and summation by using the result values in upcoming resultset.

I have tried Both Ways :

**Method 1:**

```
var list1 = List1.GetList1();
var list2 = List2.GetList12();
List<ListViewModel> listViewmodelCollection = new List<ListViewModel>();
ListViewModel listViewmodelInstance = new ListViewModel();


foreach (var _list1 in list1)
{
    listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues1 = _list1.LocationValues1;
    listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues2 = _list1.LocationValues2;

    foreach (var _list2 in list2)
    {
        listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues5 = _list2.LocationValues5;
        listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues4 = _list2.LocationValues4;
        listViewmodelInstance.RA = _list1.LocationValues1 + _list2.LocationValues4;
        listViewmodelCollection.Add(listViewmodelInstance);

    }
}
```

**Method2:**

```
List<ListViewModel> listViewmodelCollection = new List<ListViewModel>();
ListViewModel  listViewmodelInstance = new ListViewModel();
var x = (from listobj in m.list
         from n in m.list2
         select new list4
         {

             LocationValues1 = listobj.LocationValues1,
             LocationValues2 = n.LocationValues4,
             LocationValues4 = listobj.LocationValues1 + n.LocationValues4
         });
```

**-- complete --**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace simple
{
    class Program
    {
        public class List2
        {
            public string ContinentName { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues4 { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues5 { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }

            public static List<List2> GetList12()
            {
                var list2 = new List<List2>
                {
                    new List2{ ContinentName="Asia",LocationValues4=399.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M  },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Africa",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Australia",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Pakistan",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                };

                return list2;
            }
        }


        public class List1
        {
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues1 { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues2 { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }



            public static List<List1> GetList1()
            {
                var list1 = new List<List1>
                {
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=299.23M,LocationValues2=24.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=399.23M,LocationValues2=25.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=499.23M,LocationValues2=26.90M },
                };

                return list1;
            }
        }

        public class ListViewModel
        {
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues1 { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues2 { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LocationCreatedDate { get; set; }

            public decimal RA { get; set; }

            public string ContinentName { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues4 { get; set; }
            public decimal LocationValues5 { get; set; }

            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ContinentCreatedDate { get; set; }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = List1.GetList1();
            var list2 = List2.GetList12();
            List<ListViewModel> listViewmodelCollection = new List<ListViewModel>();
            ListViewModel listViewmodelInstance = new ListViewModel();


            foreach (var _list1 in list1)
            {
                listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues1 = _list1.LocationValues1;
                listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues2 = _list1.LocationValues2;

                foreach (var _list2 in list2)
                {
                    listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues5 = _list2.LocationValues5;
                    listViewmodelInstance.LocationValues4 = _list2.LocationValues4;
                    listViewmodelInstance.RA = _list1.LocationValues1 + _list2.LocationValues4;
                    listViewmodelCollection.Add(listViewmodelInstance);

                }
            }
        }
```

Expected Output:
    4 Rows

```
LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M,ContinentName="Asia",LocationValues4=399.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M, RA=598.46
LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=299.23M,LocationValues2=24.90M ,ContinentName ="Africa",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M,RA=465.46
LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=399.23M,LocationValues2=25.90M ContinentName ="Australia",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M,RA=598.46
LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=499.23M,LocationValues2=26.90M , ContinentName ="Pakistan",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M.RA=698.46
```

But current output:

[image]

Comment: In Method 1, where do you assign `ContinentName`? In Method 2, what is `m` and `list4`?

Comment: Why isn't `RA` a method that returns `LocationValues1+LocationValues4` ? (and why are the names plural???)

Answer (score 1):

So, this seems messy at best. I'm not sure what your situation is but I would be very nervous about coding to merge 2 different data lists and expecting them to always be equal lengths etc..

I would strongly recommend that you add an interface to both lists so you could at least cast them to a base object and work with them that way instead.

That said I would try to select out the view model attributes via linq from the first set, then iterate through to add the data from the 2nd set and do the computations then.

Example:

```
    var list1 = List1.GetList1();
    var list2 = List2.GetList12();
    List<ListViewModel> listViewmodelCollection = new List<ListViewModel>();
    ListViewModel listViewmodelInstance = new ListViewModel();

    listViewmodelCollection.AddRange(list1.Select(l => new ListViewModel()
    {
        LocationName = l.LocationName,
        LocationCreatedDate = l.CreatedDate,
        LocationValues1 = l.LocationValues1,
        LocationValues2 = l.LocationValues2
    }));
    for (int i = 0; i < (listViewmodelCollection.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        var itm2 = list2.ElementAt(i);
        if (itm2 != null)
        {
            listViewmodelCollection[i].ContinentName = itm2.ContinentName;
            listViewmodelCollection[i].ContinentCreatedDate = itm2.CreatedDate;
            listViewmodelCollection[i].LocationValues4 = itm2.LocationValues4;
            listViewmodelCollection[i].LocationValues5 = itm2.LocationValues5;
            listViewmodelCollection[i].RA = listViewmodelCollection[i].LocationValues1 + itm2.LocationValues4;
        }
    }
```

Given your classes this should get you to the output you wanted, at least for this narrow example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to combine the two `List`s using the `Zip` extension method:

```
var listViewmodelCollection = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => new ListViewModel {
    LocationName = l1.LocationName,
    LocationValues1 = l1.LocationValues1,
    LocationValues2 = l1.LocationValues2,
    ContinentName = l2.ContinentName,
    LocationValues4 = l2.LocationValues4,
    LocationValues5 = l2.LocationValues5,
    RA = l1.LocationValues1+l2.LocationValues4
}).ToList();
```